# How can I add a wait time without creating multiple progress bars using TKinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, progress-bar, sleep

I'm working on a script that increases the progress bar based on a variable max. I would like a delay between updates but keep running into issues.

I had originally tried using time.sleep(), but that was causing other issues. I then saw a thread stating to use an if loop with .after(1000, *, count+1). Initially, this caused an error because my original function did not contain any arguments. However, now that I have added the min_count argument, I'm getting multiple progress bars rather than just updating the one that I initially created. My code is below. I've commented out some of my edits to track and be able to rollback if needed.

```
import time
import subprocess
import os    
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
""" Create Subroutines """

""" Progress Bar """
def pb(min_count=1):
    barhour = enthour.get()
    barmin = entmin.get()
    pbhour = int (barhour)
    pbmin = int (barmin)
    timer = (pbhour * 60) + pbmin
    """total_min = timer"""
    """min_count = 1"""
    progbar = ttk.Progressbar(orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, length = 300, maximum=timer)
    progbar.pack()
    """ Do While Loop """
    if min_count <= timer:
        progbar['value'] += 1
        """timer -= 1"""
        window.after(1000, pb, min_count+1)
                
    
        
        
        
""" TKInter Build"""        
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Maker Cam")
greeting = tk.Label(text="Welcome to Maker Cam!")
greeting.pack()
space = tk.Label()
space.pack()
hourgreet = tk.Label(text="Enter the run hours.")
hourgreet.pack()
enthour = tk.Entry()
enthour.pack()
mingreet = tk.Label(text="Enter the run minutes.")
mingreet.pack()
entmin = tk.Entry()
entmin.pack()
B = Button(window, text ="OK", command = pb)
B.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

[multiple bars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRnIz.png)

Comment: You need to create the progress bar outside of the function called by `after`

Comment: @Bryan Oakley I'm trying to do this. However, I keep getting undefined errors. Should I declare global variables and create the progress bar in my main code labeled "TKInter Build"?

Comment: Try it and see what happens.

Comment: I haven't been able to look at my program in a bit, work has been a bit crazy and right now Python is a hobby. However, after doing some more research, I found out that it appears that I am trying to do too much in a single function, and it would be better to create multiple smaller functions. When I can get back to it, I'll let you know the result and post the completed code.